# how to change color of a:visited in script

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the text of the navbar on scroll to white. This works for the dropdown menu and I got it working for the home button. However, because it's an 'a' selector, it sees it as a link and thus when it is clicked on (visited) it will get the visited color. So I made an `.test a:visited {color:inherit;}'` but this also doesn't fix the problem. If I add `.navbar .test {color:black;}`then it won't become white on scroll anymore. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(2,2,2,0.5)";
    $('.dropbtn').addClass('whitenavbar');
    $('.test').addClass('whitenavbar');

  } else {
    document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    $('.dropbtn').removeClass('whitenavbar');
    $('.test').removeClass('whitenavbar');
  }

}
```

```css
.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
  top: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .test {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 25px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.whitenavbar {
  color: white;
}

.test a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="test" href="http://2019.igem.org/Team:TUDelft"><b>Home</b></a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- force scroll -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused, because your Home changes to white on scroll in your snippet.  Edit: or is it just the :visited issue?

Comment: try this`.navbar .whitenavbar {color: white;}` instead `.whitenavbar {color: white;}` in style

Comment: @Taplar it is indeed the visited issue. So the color of home is purple. if I add '.navbar .test {color:black}' then the color won't change to white on scroll. So it's one or the other..

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is one of style declarations of equal specificity competing with each other.

Give the `<a>` elements in the `.navbar` a specific class like:

```
<a class="navbarAnchor">
```

Then you can explicitly style:

```
.navbarAnchor {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

in various contexts without needing to refer to relationships between the anchors and their parent / ancestor elements.

If necessary (and it might well not be), you can reference:

```
  .navbarAnchor,
  .navbarAnchor:link,
  .navbarAnchor:visited,
  .navbarAnchor:hover,
  .navbarAnchor:active {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

---

**N.B.** It's not for everyone and it's not suitable for every situation but **BEM** methodology (and related methodologies like **ABEM**) is a very good way to tame specificity issues in CSS.

After I first came across **BEM**, I ignored it for years, because it was quite counter to the way I had been working.

I came back to it late last year and appreciated far more than I ever had before how its deliberate focus on class-based rather than relationship-based selectors can hugely simplify the maintenance of stylesheets, by ensuring almost every selector in your stylesheet has the same specificity level.

Here is a good place to start:

https://css-tricks.com/abem-useful-adaptation-bem/